# Looking for a (linux) replacement for my android tablet

Tags: linux, android, tablet

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab-"E".  It is pretty small and light weight.  about 8.5"x 
5.25".  I carry the tablet just about everywhere with me but only use it for web browsing and watching videos which I have on an SD card.

Does anyone know of a replacement I can buy so I can run native Linux?  I use mint and Debian at home, I don't like the bloat-ware that comes on the Samsung tablet.

I was thinking about getting a small laptop, but then it will be heavy and it will need to boot when I want to use it.  This is inconvenient.

Comment: check out what hardware Sailfish OS/ Jolla runs on.  Some Sony phones can be adjusted to run Jolla, not sure about tablets.  https://jolla.com

Answer (score 1):

I have not find any tablets form the market with Linux pre installed, if we do not count some originally Windows based notebooks ( with touch screen ).

But if you go the knowledge you could try installing for example Ubuntu with Gnome 3 to your current tablet, or buy new tablet and install Linux on that.

There is many guides in the internet, **but please be careful**, because you may make your devices unbootable if you are not careful.

If you wish to try installing Linux on your Android tablet **please make lot of research** about the subject, i have not tried this by my self, but i know it to be possible.

[Here is some information about the subject.](https://www.techulator.com/resources/9064-How-install-Ubuntu-Android-OS-mobile-tablet-tutorial.aspx)